# How to aggregate response from multiple channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've a spring-integration implementation with following:

1. Multiple publishing channels publishing on one common channel.
2. All the channels returns same response object.
3. Aggregator trying to aggregate response from all the above channels

Issue: Aggregator not able to combine all the responses together and provided method gets invoked on the first reponse from the channels

Here are the details. What is that I've to do to aggregate the responses?

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="aggregate-channel" apply-sequence="true"/>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="input-channel" apply-sequence="true"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="aggregate-channel" ref="...A" method="...A">
<int:service-activator input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="aggregate-channel" ref="...B" method="...B">
<int:service-activator input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="aggregate-channel" ref="...C" method="...C">
<int:service-activator input-channel="input-channel" output-channel="aggregate-channel" ref="...D" method="...D">

<!--This is the aggregator. 
**Expecting a list of size 4 but then it gets list of size 1 for each response channel
-->
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregate-channel" output-channel="gateway-response-channel" ref="Service" method="responseListProcessor"/>
```

Comment: responseListProcessor check the processes the input list based on custom business logic to send the gateway response.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

- Replace

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="aggregate-channel" apply-sequence="true"/>
```

```
    with
```

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="aggregate-channel"/>
```

**Issue**

- Initially it starts with sequence size `4` because `input-channel` has `4` subscribers
- But when you add the attribute `apply-sequence="true"` to `aggregate-channel`, it reset the sequence size to `1` because `aggregate-channel` has only one subscriber which is the `aggregator`.

**Reference**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel

> If you provide a aggregator downstream from a PublishSubscribeChannel, you can set the 'apply-sequence' property on the channel to true.

> Doing so indicates that the channel should set the sequence-size and sequence-number message headers as well as the correlation ID prior to passing along the messages.

> For example, if there are five subscribers, the sequence-size would be set to 5, and the messages would have sequence-number header values ranging from 1 to 5.

Comment: spring-integration handles the co-relation strategy and release strategy when you use apply-sequence=true on channel with aggregator combination. I'm trying to use the out of the box implementation for that. Made minor edits check that.

Comment: I have got it working. If you remove `apply-sequence="true"` from `aggregate-channel` ,  it batches 4 messages together as you have 4 subscribers to `input-channel`

Answer (score 0):

I would say your requirement is fully covered by specific for this kinda of tasks EIP - Scatter-Gather: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather